# How to use the RapidAPI in Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, vba, rest

I'm new to using RapidAPI. I want to pull live Cricket Scores from RapidAPI with Excel VBA, but the programming language isn't available on the platform.

I would like to know if there is anyway I can view the json results directly through a browser. This is what I read in their documentation https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/getting-started-with-rapidapi-sdks but doesn't seem to solve my problem

[image]

"What If the Programming Language I'm Using Isn't Available?
Whether the programming language you're using isn't available or you prefer to use another request library, have no fear! All of the APIs available on RapidAPI are exposed through a REST API endpoint. All you'll need to do is take the information provided on the documentation provided. Here's an example of what that would look like using the 'request' npm module"

```
   var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: API_URL,
  headers: { 
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': API_KEY,
    'header1': 'header-value-1'
  },
  qs: { 
    parameter1: 'parameter-value-1' 
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(body);
});
```

I'm looking for a better idea of working with RapidAPI in Excel VBA. If I can get the json response directly in a browser that solves my problem. But if that's not possible, any example to setup a Node.JS server offline and possibly display the json response in a browser may also work. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the actual API endpoint you are trying to access? And as you mention VBA - is using vba to write to Excel sheet an option?

Comment: I've updated the question with a screenshot showing the API endpoint. I dont know if I should display the key publicly. About using VBA, there is no option like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Const Covid19URL As String = "https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/history?day=2020-03-25&country=Malaysia"
Const APIKey As String = "brx2HKOJvP6iQ14WxeumLmnhx2L2MAZz"

Sub Main()
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim xmlresponse As New DOMDocument60

    xmlhttp.Open "GET", Covid19URL, False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "x-rapidapi-host", "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com"
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "x-rapidapi-key", APIKey

    xmlhttp.send

    Cells(2, 12).Value = xmlhttp.responseText
    'xmlresponse.LoadXML (xmlhttp.responseText)

    '"response":[
    '{"country":"Malaysia","cases":{"new":"+172","active":1596,"critical":64,"recovered":183,"total":1796},"deaths":{"new":"+1","total":17},"day":"2020-03-25","time":"2020-03-25T09:15:07+00:00"},
    '{"country":"Malaysia","cases":{"new":"+172","active":1597,"critical":64,"recovered":183,"total":1796},"deaths":{"new":null,"total":16},"day":"2020-03-25","time":"2020-03-25T07:15:06+00:00"},
    '{"country":"Malaysia","cases":{"new":"+106","active":1425,"critical":64,"recovered":183,"total":1624},"deaths":{"new":"+2","total":16},"day":"2020-03-25","time":"2020-03-25T06:15:05+00:00"}

    Set xmlresponse = Nothing
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation of your answer and not just code.